# SilverStripe ListboxField multiselect sort by user select

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a `many_many` relation between my `Theses` and `Subjects`. I created a `ListboxField` w/c accepts multiple values.

Saving it to the database was not a problem but when I view the information again the subject sorts the user selection base on the `ID` of the subject.

For example, the user selects the order `[1,5,4,2]`. Once saved and viewed again it will display like this `[1,2,4,5]`.

Here is my code:

**Theses.php**

```
class Theses extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'CallNo' => 'Varchar',
        'AuthorID' => 'Int',
        'TitleTH' => 'Text',
        'Year' => 'Int(4)',
        'PhysicalDesc' => 'Text',
        'Notes' => 'Text',
        'Summary' => 'Text',
        'DegreeCourse' => 'Varchar'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Author' => 'Author'
    );

    private static $field_labels = array(
        'CallNo' => 'Call Number',
        'TitleTH' => 'Title Headings',
        'Author.AuthorName' => 'Author',
        'DegreeCourse' => 'Degree Course',
        'Year' => 'Year Published',
        'SubjectsString' => 'Subject'
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'CallNo' => 'CallNo',
        'TitleTH' => 'TitleTH',
        'Author.AuthorName',
        'DegreeCourse',
        'Year' => 'Year',
        'SubjectsString'
    );

    private static $many_many = array(
        'Subjects' => 'Subject'
    );

    public function SubjectsString() {
        $returnString = '';
        foreach ($this->Subjects()->sort('Theses_Subjects.Created') as $Subjects) {
            $returnString .= $Subjects->SubjectTitle . '--';
        }
        return $returnString;
    }

    public function getCMSfields() {
        $fields = FieldList::create(TabSet::create('Root'));
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
            TextField::create('CallNo'),
            DropdownField::create('AuthorID', 'AuthorName')
                ->setSource(Author::get()->sort('AuthorName')->map('ID', 'AuthorName')),
            TextField::create('TitleTH'),
            NumericField::create('Year', 'Year')
                ->setMaxLength(4),
            TextField::create('PhysicalDesc'),
            TextField::create('Notes'),
            TextAreaField::create('Summary'),
            DropdownField::create('DegreeCourse', 'DegreeCourse', array('BLIS' => 'BLIS', 'BLS' => 'BLS', 'MLIS' => 'MLIS', 'MLS' => 'MLS')),
            ListboxField::create('Subjects', 'Subjects', Subject::get()->map('ID', 'SubjectTitle')->toArray(), 1, 4, true),
        ));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

**Subject.php**

```
class Subject extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'SubjectTitle' => 'Varchar'
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Theses' => 'Theses'
    );

    public function canView($member = null) {
        return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
    }

    public function canEdit($member = null) {
        return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
    }

    public function canDelete($member = null) {
        return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
    }

    public function canCreate($member = null) {
        return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
    }

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'SubjectTitle'
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a way to make the ListBox work, but could not find something for you there so instead I'm answering this question in a way that provides a similar experience but not a ListBox.

Using the [GridField Extensions Module](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions) the sorting can be added to a GridField and removing the "add new" button and leaving the add via auto complete has the same functionality.  It takes up more space - but does show the summary of the subject and allow opening of the record - as well as reordering as required.

I've only included a partial amount of the code as there were some missing objects (Author).  Also please note that for a DataObject used within ModelAdmin (which is my assumption here) you do not need to make each field as they are scaffolded for you by $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

Hope this helps

```
class Theses extends DataObject {

    ...

    private static $many_many = array(
        'Subjects' => 'Subject'
    );

    public static $many_many_extraFields = array(
        'Subjects' => array(
            'SortOrder' => 'Int',
        ),
    );

    ...

    public function getCMSfields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $gridSubjects = $fields->dataFieldByName('Subjects');
        $gridSubjects->getConfig()
            ->addComponent(GridFieldOrderableRows::create('SortOrder'))
            ->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddNewButton');

        $fields = FieldList::create(TabSet::create('Root'));
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(

            ...

            TextField::create('Notes'),
            TextAreaField::create('Summary'),
            DropdownField::create('DegreeCourse', 'DegreeCourse', array('BLIS' => 'BLIS', 'BLS' => 'BLS', 'MLIS' => 'MLIS', 'MLS' => 'MLS')),
            $gridSubjects
        ));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```